# Angular JS and Webservices

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, web-services

I am looking  to call a webservice with Angular JS.
I am new to Angular JS. I have few questions and need your expertise.
1) I am using WAMP, Do I need to use/install  some framework to make a REST call from Angular JS?
2) Please share some good advance level tutorial links. I get some mobile development related tutorials all the time.

Thanks 
Yukti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, you don't need a framework to make a REST call. You simply have to use the $httpProvider either inside a controller or inside a service

```
   $http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

2) recommend  tutorials:

- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2612-using-the-http-service-in-angularjs-to-make-ajax-requests.htm
- https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-http